# What is the analogue of Leibniz's rule for universal enveloping algebra?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a reductive group over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ its complexitied Lie algebra.
Let $U(\mathfrak{g})$ be the universal enveloping algebra and $Z(\mathfrak{g})$ is the center of $U(\mathfrak{g})$.

We know that an arbitrary element $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ can be regarded as a first order differential operator on $C^{\infty}(G)$, the space of smooth functions on $G(\mathbb{R})$, and it satisfies the Leibniz rule. That is for $f,g \in C^{\infty}(G)$, then $X(fg)=X(f)g+fX(g).$

I am wondering whether there is such an analogue of Leibniz rule for $U(\mathfrak{g})$. If such does not exists in $U(\mathfrak{g})$, such thing exists in $Z(\mathfrak{g})$?

Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: The (arguably tautological) answer is that for $X\in U(\mathfrak g)$, we have $X(fg) = \sum_i X_i'(f)\otimes X_i''(g)$, where $\Delta(X) = \sum_i X'_i\otimes X''_i$ is the coproduct of the Hopf algebra $U(\mathfrak g)$. Since $Z(\mathfrak g)$ is not closed under the coproduct, there is no obvious simplification for $X\in Z(\mathfrak g)$.

Comment: @Betram, Thanks for comment. I guess that if $X(f)=X(g)=0$ for $X\in Z(\mathfrak{g})$, then $X(fg)=0$. Do you think this hold from above? If $X \in \mathfrak{g}$, it holds but I am not sure for $X \in Z(\mathfrak{g})$.

Comment: No ($G = (S^1)^2, X = \partial_{x_1}\partial_{x_2}, f = \sin x_1, g = \sin x_2$).

Comment: @Bertram, thank you for good counterexample. It helped my understanding. By the way, may I ask a stupid question? In your first reply, you write $\Delta(X)=\sum_i X_i\prime \otimes X_i \prime \prime$. But for $X \in Z(\mathfrak{g})$, does it not hold? I mean, can we not sure that $X_i\prime, X_i\prime \prime \in Z(\mathfrak{g})$? Is that you mean $Z(\mathfrak{g})$ is not closed  coproduct?

Comment: @Bertram, I think when $G$ is a classical group, then your first reply also applies to center because the center has Hopf algebra structure.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question - as I wrote, the center is not closed under the coproduct, i.e. $\Delta Z(\mathfrak g)$ is not contained in $Z(\mathfrak g)\otimes Z(\mathfrak g)$, e.g. for $\mathfrak g$ simple the coproduct of the Casimir element lies in $\mathfrak g\otimes\mathfrak g\subset U(\mathfrak g)^{\otimes 2}$.

Comment: @Bertram, When $\mathfrak{g}$ is the reductive Lie algebra, then $Z(\mathfrak{g})$ is known to be polynomial algebra by Harish-Chandra isomorphism. So if $\mathfrak{g}$ is of rank $n$, then $Z(\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$. And as you know, $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ has coproduct given by $\Delta(x_i)=x_i \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes x_i$. That’s why I think $Z(\mathfrak{g})$ is closed under coproduct at least for reductive algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: The two coproducts don't agree.

Comment: @Bertram, Oh, I see! It depends on the definition of coproduct of $Z(\mathfrak{g})$. When we use coproduct of $Z(\mathfrak{g})$ induced by polynomial ring, your first comment holds also even for $Z(\mathfrak{g})$. That is, if $\Delta(X)=\sum X_i’ \otimes X_i’’$ for $X_i’,  X_i’’ \in Z(\mathfrak{g})$, then $X(fg)=\sum X_i’(f) X_i’’(g)$. But if we use coproduct inherited from $U(\mathfrak{g})$, we cannot ensure that $X_i’,X_i’’ \in Z(\mathfrak{g})$. Thank you for your clarification!